# How to scale the active slider in swiper js

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am trying to scale up the active slider to 1.1 in mobile devices. I am using `slideChange` method to get the active slider with `swiper.realIndex`.
I have successfully scaled up the first slider on start using `init` method but it is not working on slide change.

Working codepen https://codepen.io/bhanusinghR/pen/QWbERom?editors=1010

I want the active slider to be scaled up and the rest to be of default size on mobile devices.
Thanks in advance.